# Sick Betta fish - insecticide exposure

Tags: fish, betta

My Betta was exposed to insecticides over the summer and became very ill. He is still with us 4 months later but hardly moves at all and lays at the bottom of the tank. I significantly reduced the water because he was having trouble getting to the top. Initially, he improved a bit but there’s been no progress since. I feel so bad for him. Thanks for any useful advice.

Comment: please add this information how big is your tank,type of filtration and heating,the readings of your water test ammonia-nitrite-ph-nitrate.

Comment: Water temperature should be around 80 F.

Comment: Is he still in the same tank he was in when he was exposed to insecticide?

Comment: give him 10 gallons or more, a filter, and frequent partial water changes and then let's see if the problem persists